# send encrypted message from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm trying to get two services to talk but I need to encrypt the message sent between them. It's early days so I'm hard coding the key, but here is what I have so far.

In c#

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("QM3M8+Zbw5VYa70xtftksHHqM1UGmhOBjqOP82UtuAA=");
byte[] hexiv = Convert.FromBase64String("wRt00heBiu86mWSfuHmSag==");
using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
  {
    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(name, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
    string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
  }
.....


static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

This outputs my message as `+CPJqIL6RhIHc5+u2Nvonw==`

Then in PHP, I have the following:

```
$key = "Zbw5VYa70xtftksHHqM1UGmhOBjqOP82UtuAA=";
$hexiv = "wRt00heBiu86mWSfuHmSag==";
$string = base64_decode("+CPJqIL6RhIHc5+u2Nvonw==");

$cipher_alg = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt($cipher_alg, $key, $string , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $hexiv);
echo $decrypted_string."<BR>";
```

But this is giving me `Qˆ–â¤»?/P¸Üu:·ey+–Uñ :,yL±­M`

Hopefully the answer is fairly obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: are the services talking via http? why encrypt yourself when you could simply use ssl?

Comment: I would prefer to use SSL but this may not be possible so I need to be prepared. Plus I would like to  learn why it's going wrong anyway.

Comment: Hopefully the last five years and the advent of LetsEncrypt allowed you to install TLS 1.2 and newer for transport-layer encryption, and just use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You fell for [the mcrypt trap](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` isn't AES-256, it's the 256-bit block size variant of Rijndael. AES is always a 128-bit block size even with 256-bit keys.

Look into [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages) instead. There are bindings for .NET and PHP. If you upgrade to PHP 7.2 or higher, you should have it installed already.